# Can we find the probability by counting the outcomes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A purse contains 2 silver and 4 copper coins. A second purse contains 4 silver and 3 copper coins. If a coin is pulled at random from one of the two purses, what is the probability that it is a silver coin?

We can solve this problem by applying the law of total probability and the answer is 19/42.

My question is: can we solve this problem by counting the total number and favourable number of outcomes? If yes how and if no why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that to get the correct probabilities with counting favourable/all outcomes, your outcomes need to all have the same probabilities. This isn't true in this problem, so the counting technuique will not work in this example.

The "not-mentioned information" in the problem description that has to be inferred from the text is that you do **two** random choices:

1. You choose the purse at random first (each with probability $0.5$).
2. You then choose a coin at random (uniform distribution) from all the coins in the selected purse.

Because of that, the probability that any specific coin from purse 1 is selected is $\frac12\times\frac16=\frac1{12}$, because you need to select purse 1 in step 1 above (probability is $\frac12$) and then choose that specific coin from the 6 coins in that purse in step 2.

Similiarly, the probability to select any specific coin from purse 2 is $\frac12 \times \frac17 = \frac1{14}$.

Notably, the probabilities are **different**. This means that the counting technique of

1. 13 coins in total that can be selected and
2. 6 of those are silver coins

leads to the **incorrect** result that the asked for probability is $\frac6{13}$.

If we distribute the coins more extremely, the differences between the approaches becomes more obvious.

Say purse 1 comes from a medivial beggar and contains just 1 copper coin, while purse 2 comes from a nobleman and contains 100 silver coins.

If we ask the question again, what is the probability to select a silver coin from a randomly selected purse, it becomes clear that step 1, (choose a purse at random) is the all important one, because step 2 (choose a coin from the purse at random) is not important at all.

So the answer in this case is simply $p=\frac12$. This is in stark contrast to the counting method, which says we have 101 coins, 100 of which are silver. The reason is that choosing a specific silver coin is very unlikely ($\frac1{200}$), while slecting the one copper coin has probability $\frac12$.

So if you want to apply the counting method and use the formula that the probability is favourable outcomes divided by all outcomes, you need to make **absolutely sure** that all the outcomes you are counting have the same probability.